# Difference in meaning between "esteem ~for" and "esteem~ of"?

Tags: meaning

What is the difference in meaning between "esteem ~for" and
"esteem~ of" ?

1) I esteem him **for** his diligence.

2) I esteem his diligence **of** him.

Does "1 )I esteem him for his diligence" mean "I esteem him, because he is diligent" ?

Does "2) I esteem his diligence of him" mean " I esteem not him but his diligence" ?

(Source: naver korean-english dictionary

[image]
 and 
 in a pamphlet made by someone to use as an educational resource in English.

And google translator,
[image]

Comment: Could you say where you have seen these, if you have? I’ve never seen the latter.

Comment: I saw this in a english-korean dictionary and in a pamphlet made by someone to use as an educational resource in English. And the interpretation in Korean there was the same. -->[1) I esteem him for his diligence. 나는 그의 부지런함을 존경한다. 2) I esteem his diligence of him. 나는 그의 부지런함을 존경한다. ] But I think the meaning of these two sentences may be different,